# Layout constraint in expandable UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a button in my `UITableViewCell` which has to expand that cell. I have some vertical layout constraints in my cell which I have to modify upon expanding to rearrange the subviews.

I returned the height of each cell in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

After the user scrolls, the expanded cell has to be still expanded when it comes back on the screen, of course. So in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (I tried it also in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` with the same result) I do something like:

```
if ([_indexPathOfExpandedCell isEqual:indexPath]) {
    [cell setConstraintToLargeValue];
} else {
    [cell setConstraintToSmallValue];
}
```

The problem is, when the expanded cell comes back to the screen and the `setConstraintToLargeValue` gets called, when I try to increase the `constant` property of the vertical constraint, I get an

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

message. What I figured out so far is that at the point of modifying the constraint the `cell` has the correct height (the one I return in `heightFor...`), however the `cell.contentView` has a much smaller height from before the expansion and this is what is causing the the error. Does anybody have a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Instead of triggering the change of the constraint from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I only set a flag on the cell `isExpanded`, and modify the constraint in the `layoutSubviews` method, where after calling `[super layoutSubviews]` the `cell.contentView` becomes the same height as `cell` and I no longer get conflict between the constraints.